# Are shapely values invariant under monotonic feature transformation?

Tags: importance, shapley-value

I have been using shap values as a measure of feature importance for some time. But, I have never understood the justification behind comparing the shap values for features that are on different scales.

Shap values represent the average change in the prediction if the feature changes by 1 unit. But, what if one of my features ranges from [0,1000000] and the other one ranges from [1,2]

Another way to state this would be to ask if the shap values are invariant under the monotonic transformations of the feature

would SHAP(X) be equal to SHAP(f(X))? I don't see a reason why It should be and then using them for feature importance does not make sense to me

Can you please help me understand shapely values from this angle?

Comment: Where did you come to the conclusion that "Shap values represent the average change in the prediction if the feature changes by 1 unit."?

Comment: Do you have a particular kind of model in mind?

Comment: I do not know where I came to that conclusion but I read up on it again and it definitely completely wrong. Shapely is, as I now understand (maybe still wrong?) - You take all different sets (coalitions) of features without the feature in question. You compute the predictions without this feature (this would be the marginalized prediction over all the features not included in the coalition). Similarly, you compute the prediction with the feature present. The average difference between the two predictions is the shapely value. I am working on lightgbm model

Comment: Do this thought experiment: The Shapley values for a linear model are the $\hat{\beta} x_i$s. With this in mind, how would transforming $x_i$ change the Shapley values?